# EF6 code first to 6NF tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, 6nf

I have the following database model

```
Entity
Id, ...

PropertyType
Id, Name, DataType, ...

EntityProperty
Id, EntityId, PropertyTypeId

PropertyValueString
Id, Value

PropertyValueDateTime
ID, Value
```

I am using EF6 code first to map my entities to this data model

```
class Entity {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  ...
}

class PropertyType {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Type DataType { get; set; }
  ...
}


class EntityProperty {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
  public Entity Entity { get; set; }
  public Guid PropertyTypeId { get; set; }
  public PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
  public string StringValue { get; set; }
  public DateTime? DateTimeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping Entity and PropertyType class to respective tables is straight forward.
EntityProperty is mapped using

```
Map(m => m.ToTable("EntityProperty").Properties(p => new { p.Id, p.EntityId, p.PropertyTypeId });
Map(m => m.ToTable("PropertyValueString").Properties(p => new { p.Id, p.StringValue });
Map(m => m.ToTable("PropertyValueDateTime").Properties(p => new { p.Id, p.DateTimeValue });
```

How do I map my EntityProperty to `PropertyValueString` or `PropertyValueDateTime` tables depending on which field has value? Also, the query generated when including EntityProperty should `LEFT JOIN` with PropertyValueString and PropertyValueDateTime.

Is this even possible with Entity Framework?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to outsmart the ORM ("Also, the query generated when including EntityProperty should `LEFT JOIN` with [...]"). If you work with ORM, leave the internals like the join strategy to the ORM and concern yourself with more high level design properties. Another thing: The `Type` property will most probably produce an error when you try to generate database tables from it.

Comment: @grek40 I understand about the Type field, this was just to illustrate that PropertyType is a sort of meta table which describes the property and may have additional metadata e.g. IsRequired etc.

Comment: If you wrap `StringValue` and `DateTimeValue` into a sub class each and have them inherit the same base class, an EF table per type hierarchy might be somewhat close to what you want. However, I get the feeling that your problem and your question are not really the same thing.

Comment: @grek40 The problem is when creating the mapping as described in the question EF assumes a 1-1 relation between EntityProperty, PropertyValueString, and PropertyValueDateTime. However what I want is 1-0..1 relationship between EntityProperty and PropertyValueString and PropertyValueDateTime and only 1 of them will have a corresponding record for a given EntityProperty.Id. After reading the conditions for entity splitting at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896233.aspx I need to revisit my classes so will try TPT. Thanks

Comment: You are confusing EAV with 6NF.  The (necessary) 6NF of EAV tables does not guarantee 6NF relevant to your application. EAV stores *metadata*, ie encodes the table(s) actually relevant to an application into a collection of other tables. Your entities are your application entities *plus* entities that are parts of tables representing application entities & relationships. Eg 6nf application table person "person with id *i* at time *t* had name *n*" row <i, t, n> is encoded (ignoring types) by rows property(i, p, "name"), string(p,string(n)) & time(p,t). The 6NF of the EAV tables is irrelevant.